# Tabbing through next text input not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to pass focus to next text input on press of buttons.Everything was working fine till when I created customTextInput in another class and calling it through props.But now problem is focus is not changing on button press and I think it is related to some scope problem .Maybe it is not accessing **this** of other class(child component).
Following is the stuff I had done:

> This is Custom Text input I had created in other js file

```
    <View>
      <CustomTextInput
      textLogo={logo}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      value={value}
      onChangeText={onTextChange}
      isMultiline={isMultiline}
      onFocus={() =>
     {
        this.setState({index:index,isFocused:true})
        this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: position, animated: true })}
      }
      ref={input =>(this[arrTextInput[index]] = input)}/>
   </View>
```

> This is function for changing the focus

```
  customFocusNavigator = () => {
  return(
  <View style={styles.FocusNavigator}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this[arrTextInput[this.state.index - 1]].focus()}} style={styles.bottomSubView}>
    <Text>Previous</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() =>{this[arrTextInput[this.state.index + 1]].focus()}} style={styles.bottomSubView}>
    <Text>Next</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
)
}
```

And I am changing index of textInput on focus .
I hope I gave sufficient matter for my problem.Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: is there any error or something?

Comment: NO ...simply keyboard is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a function to change the focus, you can simply do it using **onSubmitEditing**

For example with 3 inputs you could do it like this:

```
<Input
  placeHolder="Input1"
  ref={input => (this.Input1 = input)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => {this.Input2.focus(); }}
/>
<Input
  placeHolder="Input2"
  ref={input => (this.Input2 = input)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => {this.Input3.focus(); }}
/>
<Input
  placeHolder="Input3"
  ref={input => (this.Input3 = input)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => **GO SOMEWHERE ELSE** }}
/>
```

You set the **ref** on the later input and then pass the **focus()** on the previous one

Comment: But what if I want focus on previous one

Comment: if you press tab you want to go to the previous one? if yes, you can change the 'onSubmitEditing' to point to the ref of the previous input